# how to run an Ansible command for specific number of hosts

Tags: ansible, linux, automation, centos

I am new to Ansible and i have a question about limitting hosts in a host group at running commands.I have these host groups in my inventory:

```
[primary]  
host1  
host2  
[standby]  
host3  
host4
```

i have thses configuration in my `.yml`:

```
  ---
  - hosts: primary
  roles:
     - automation
```

for example i want to run this command `ansible -playbook -i /path  test.yml --tags automation` on `host2` only. what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`--limit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html?highlight=--limit) option to select a subset of hosts:

```
ansible-playbook -i /path  test.yml --tags automation --limit host2
```

Its description from [ansible-playbook documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-l):

> further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern

Comment: i found these too: `--limit 'standby,primary'` and `--limit 'standby:!host3'`